# Trying to read a table on Trigger during update, giving mutation error

Tags: oracle, plsql, mutating-table

Before updating a table I have to insert in another table, but to accomplish that I need information from the table (and other tables) which I'm updating, trying to read my updating table in the trigger is giving an error

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-04091: table BASEDATOS2.SOL_SOLICITUD_PREMIOS is mutating, trigger/function
>   may not see it
>   ORA-06512: at "BASEDATOS2.INS_AFTER_UPD_PRICES", line 10
>   ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'BASEDATOS2.INS_AFTER_UPD_PRICES'

Here´s my trigger

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INS_AFTER_UPD_PRICES BEFORE UPDATE OF CONCEDIDO ON SOL_SOLICITUD_PREMIOS 
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (new.CONCEDIDO = 'S')
DECLARE
    DESDE DATE;
    HASTA DATE;
    MONTO NUMBER;
    MAX_ID NUMBER;
    v_mov_premio NUMBER;
    CUENTA NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(ID_MOVIMIENTO)+1 INTO MAX_ID FROM AHO_MOVIMIENTOS_CUENTA;
    SELECT SSP.FECHA_DESDE,SSP.FECHA_HASTA,SE.MONTO_COBERTURA INTO DESDE,HASTA,MONTO
    FROM SOL_SOLICITUD_PREMIOS SSP JOIN SOL_EVENTOS SE
    ON SE.COD_EVENTO = SSP.COD_EVENTO 
    WHERE SE.COD_EVENTO=:OLD.COD_EVENTO
    AND SSP.ID=:OLD.ID;

    select id_tipo into v_mov_premio
            from aho_tipo_movimiento
            where UPPER(nombre_tipo) like '%PAGO DE PREMIO/SUBSIDIO%';

    SELECT AM.ID_CUENTA INTO CUENTA 
    FROM AHO_MOVIMIENTOS_CUENTA AM
    JOIN AHO_TIPO_MOVIMIENTO ATM ON ATM.ID_TIPO=AM.ID_TIPO
    WHERE ATM.ID_TIPO='A' AND ROWNUM=1;

    INSERT INTO AHO_MOVIMIENTOS_CUENTA 
    VALUES(MAX_ID, SYSDATE, MONTO*(HASTA-DESDE),v_mov_premio,CUENTA );
END;
```

Anyone knows how can I make it work?

Comment: Your table is mutating because you're updating it. Hence using select to this table in the trigger is not valid. Move that logic out of trigger.

Comment: I don't know how to move the logic out an still make it work

Comment: You can write an anonymous block, stored procedure, package, etc.. which will under transaction do all these action outside of trigger. Even to have so much SQL execution in the trigger can't be a great idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your trigger is defined on `SOL_SOLICITUD_PREMIOS`, and in the body of the trigger you're SELECTing data *from* SOL_SOLICITUD_PREMIOS. In ROW triggers you're not allowed to read, insert, update, or delete other rows in the table which the trigger is defined on because it could cause a trigger loop, where the database gets stuck evaluating recursive invocations of the same trigger. However, in this case reading data from `SOL_SOLICITUD_PREMIOS` is not needed because you already have the data you need available to you in the `:OLD` pseudo-row. If I'm reading things correctly you can rewrite your trigger as follows and it should do what you're looking for:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INS_AFTER_UPD_PRICES
  BEFORE UPDATE OF CONCEDIDO ON SOL_SOLICITUD_PREMIOS 
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN (new.CONCEDIDO = 'S')
DECLARE
    MONTO         NUMBER;
    MAX_ID        NUMBER;
    v_mov_premio  NUMBER;
    CUENTA        NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(ID_MOVIMIENTO)+1 INTO MAX_ID FROM AHO_MOVIMIENTOS_CUENTA;

    SELECT SE.MONTO_COBERTURA
      INTO MONTO
      FROM SOL_EVENTOS SE 
      WHERE SE.COD_EVENTO = :OLD.COD_EVENTO;

    select id_tipo
      into v_mov_premio
      from aho_tipo_movimiento
      where UPPER(nombre_tipo) like '%PAGO DE PREMIO/SUBSIDIO%';

    SELECT AM.ID_CUENTA
      INTO CUENTA 
      FROM AHO_MOVIMIENTOS_CUENTA AM
      JOIN AHO_TIPO_MOVIMIENTO ATM
        ON ATM.ID_TIPO = AM.ID_TIPO
      WHERE ATM.ID_TIPO = 'A' AND
            ROWNUM = 1;

    INSERT INTO AHO_MOVIMIENTOS_CUENTA 
    VALUES(MAX_ID,
           SYSDATE,
           MONTO * (:OLD.FECHA_HASTA - :OLD.FECHA_DESDE),
           v_mov_premio,
           CUENTA );
END INS_AFTER_UPD_PRICES;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you! I was never going to realize if it wasn't for you.